# Regular Expression: Find words within 10 words of each other

Tags: regex

I have a requirement where I am looking for the words "house" and "car" but they have to be within 10 words of each other. I have the following regular expression:

```
(\b(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?i)car\b)|(\b(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?i)house\b)
```

This works well with any combination of words. However, this doesn't satisfy the "within 10 words of each other" requirement:

Hence, the following would be a good match:

```
car word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 house
house word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 car
```

However the following shouldn't be a match:

```
house word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word 11 car
```

car word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word 11 house

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Full words like this? https://regex101.com/r/qPfeUy/1

Answer (score 3):

If both words have to be there, but no match between the same words, you might use a capture group for either house or car.

Repeat 1-10 times any word that does not start with either of them and then match either of the words, not being the same word as group 1 using a negative lookahead.

```
\b(house|car)(?: (?!(?:house|car)\b)\w+){1,10} (?!\1)(house|car)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b(house|car)` A word boundary, capture either house or car in **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!(?:house|car)\b)\w+` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not either house or car. If that is true, match 1+ word characters
- `){1,10}` Close the group and repeat it 1-10 times
- `(?!\1)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not the same word captured in group 1
- `(house|car)\b` Capture **group 2**, match either house or car followed by a word boundary

You can change the quantifier to `{0,10}` if the word can also be the one that directly follows or change the values to fit the requirement.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BTNx1n/1)

If there can be a match between the same words:

```
\b(house|car)(?: (?!(?:house|car)\b)\w+){1,10} (house|car)\b
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AE1fja/1)

Comment: FYI: A word boundary between a space and a letter is implied.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes of course, let me update that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `/\b((?:house|car)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?(?:house|car)|(?:house|car)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,10}?(?:house|car))\b\/g`

See [example](https://regexr.com/5j4ec)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply try:

```
(car( [^ ]*){1,10} house)|(house( [^ ]*){1,10} car)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/rAu6Ku/1